# Store 3 bits of data in java Vector

Tags: java, vector, bit

I have a sort of directions, (North, Sourth, West, East, LOCAL). I choose to code them 3 bits like so (000, 001,010,011,100) respectivly. So i want to store this code in an array of Vector type. the structure of the array that i want to acheive looks like :

```
[0][3bits of data her]
[1][3bits of data her]
[2][3bits of data her]
[3][3bits of data her]
[4][3bits of data her]
[5][.................]
```

So how i can implement this idea ?

Comment: Good luck with that. Come back when you have a question.

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: How do you obtain the directions? Do they come from a String like `String s = "000, 001,010,011,100";` ? An array? What?

Comment: the directions are Constants. i have a data that moves  from router to another router from various directions.

Comment: Can you please show some more code? What do you mean they are constants? Do you have for example `static final String NORTH = "000";`? You don't provide many details. You don't even specify what the problem is. So if you need help give us more.

Comment: Look, public static int North = 0 (000); i don't to stroe the whole 32 bit of an integer, but only three bits ( 0-4 they coded by only 3 bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way of doing that is creating an enum and assign to each value the related bit string 000, 010, 001, ...

If you don't have good motivation there is no reason to use bits in java.

Anyway another way could be create a Vector and save inside it the decimal conversion of the bits you need.

For example:

```
000 = 0
001 = 1
010 = 2
```

and so on

Comment: Yeah, it looks a good idea. I have to try it .